# Catalog Rule Product index in parallel mode

Tags: magento2, indexer, magento24

In the Magento 2.4.6 Community Edition project there is an issue. An implementation of the Catalog Price parallel index has almost been done in the issue.

The size of the `catalogrule_product_price_replica` table in the project is about **15G**. There is a question about the parallel indexing process that needs to be asked somewhere.

**Can the Catalog Rule Product index also be paralleled, somehow?**

Maybe in the Magento Enterprise Edition, It had already been implemented.